# Sql pivot with multiple counts

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
select distinct 
(SELECT  COUNT (TaskID) FROM Task, Employee where SupervisorID = '752A0F4D-9905-4D55-87F1-AFA19245C206' and task.UserID = Employee.UserID) as Total,
(SELECT  COUNT (TaskID) FROM Task, Employee where SupervisorID = '752A0F4D-9905-4D55-87F1-AFA19245C206' and task.UserID = Employee.UserID and DateDue <= DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE()) )as TotalOverdue,
(SELECT  COUNT (TaskID) FROM Task, Employee where SupervisorID = '752A0F4D-9905-4D55-87F1-AFA19245C206' and task.UserID = Employee.UserID and DateDue >= DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE()) )  as Totaldue
from Task
```

It gives me the following result:

```
Total | TotalOverdue | TotalDue
5     | 4            | 1
```

However, I want it formated this way:

```
Total: 5
TotalOverdue: 4
TotalDue: 1
```

I have tried using the pivot function, but cant really get it to work properly. Any ideas?

Comment: You're looking for the [`UNION ALL`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/union_all.php) operator...

Comment: I have tried using the union all operator, but then I just ended up with data in a single column, but no way to see which row belongs to what.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*) as Total,
       sum(case when DateDue <= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) then 1 else 0
           end) as TotalOverdue,
       sum(case when DateDue >=  DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) then 1 else 0
           end) as TotalDue
from Task join
     Employee
     on task.UserID = Employee.UserID
where SupervisorID = '752A0F4D-9905-4D55-87F1-AFA19245C206';
```

If you want it for all supervisors,

```
select SupervisorID, count(*) as Total,
       sum(case when DateDue <= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) then 1 else 0
           end) as TotalOverdue,
       sum(case when DateDue >=  DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) then 1 else 0
           end) as TotalDue
from Task join
     Employee
     on task.UserID = Employee.UserID;
```

EDIT:

You really want to unpivot the data.  Here is one method:

```
select n.which,
       (case when n.which = 'Total'
             then count(*)
             when n.which = 'TotalOverdue'
             then sum(case when DateDue <= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) then 1 else 0
                                 end)
             else sum(case when DateDue >=  DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) then 1 else 0
                      end)
        end) as value
from Task join
     Employee
     on task.UserID = Employee.UserID cross join
     (select 'Total' as which union all 'TotalOverdue' union all 'TotalDue') n
group by n.which;
```

If you want one column that is a string, use `concat()`.

Comment: Your function works perfectly, but it doesnt pivot the data. It gives the same output as before.